# Braintree paypal working in ripple but not working in device mode

Tags: javascript, cordova, braintree

When migrate to the production Braintree API credential, We are facing an issue in device mode. But same thing work fine in our simulator environment(Ripple).

Please follow the Error description as bellow.
1.  First we generate the client token using our web API service. It is working fine in both device mode and simulator.

2. Secondly using client token which is generated in step 1 , We do the setting up process as bellow and for this one we use JavaScript.

   ```
   paymentService.getNewClientToken().then(function (data) {

       $scope.tokenId = data;
       braintree.setup($scope.tokenId, "custom", {
           onReady: function (integration) {
               checkout = integration;
           },
           paypal: {
               container: "paypal-container",
               intent:'sale',
               singleUse: true,//Required
               amount: $scope.shoppingCart.totalAmout, // Required
               currency: 'SGD', // Required
               locale: 'en_us',
               enableShippingAddress: false,
               headless: true
           },
           dataCollector: {
               paypal: true
           },
           onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
               $scope.shoppingCart.isDirty = false;
               $scope.showCheckOutButton = false;
               $scope.showPayNowButton = true;
               $scope.$apply();
               //myPopup.close();
               updateNonce(obj.nonce);
           }
       });
   ```

Here in onReady callback both device mode and simulator receiving the response. But Device mode response does not contain the PayPal object. Please refer bellow screenshots.

In Device Mode:

[image]

In Emulator  Mode :

[image]

Here in emulator mode you can see the paypal object inside the response, But it not there in the device mode. Because of this reason in device mode application unable to generate paypal pop-up.

Could you please help us to resolve this issue?

Comment: It appears that you do not have PayPal enabled in your production environment. Can you confirm that you have linked your PayPal account to Braintree? If you have linked your PayPal account to Braintree, I would recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for further troubleshooting.

Comment: I have alreqdy enable the paypal in my production environment. It is already working on  emulator environment and I have already  did the payment in simulator environmwnt.but not working in actuall device mode.